# Cannot GET /currentSite on refresh react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, webpack, react-router

I have a problem. I cant refresh my react components/page without getting "Cannot GET /currentPage". I've browsed you for some time now and found a couple of links that could be the solution of my issue:

https://github.com/jintoppy/react-training/blob/master/basic/node_modules/react-router/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

HashHistory of BrowserHistory. Internet said I should use BrowserHistory for production - but that hashHistory is easier. They are both so effing complicated. I cant for my life figure out how to implement it to my current code.

This is my app.js file:

```
/*global $:true*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import './scss/app.scss';

// Component imports
import Home from './components/home';
import Archive from './archive';

// Image import
import loadImg from './images/tits.gif';

class App extends Component {

  // Function for anchorlinks
  hashLinkScroll() {
    const { hash } = window.location;
    if (hash !== '') {
      // Push onto callback queue so it runs after the DOM is updated, this is required when navigating from a different page so that the element is rendered on the page before trying to getElementById
      setTimeout(() => {
        const id = hash.replace('#', '');
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element) element.scrollIntoView();
      }, 100);
    }
  }

  // 1. Render site-loader gif
  // 2. React Router component wraps all of the routes we are going to define - Archive and Home. Each route will be identified in a <Route> component. The <Route> component will take two properties: path and component. When a path matches the path given to the <Route> component, it will return the component specified.
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="loaderSmall">
          <img className="loadingImg" src={loadImg} width="400"/>
        </div>
        <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={this.hashLinkScroll}>
          <Route path={'/archive'} component={Archive} />
          <Route path={'*'} component={Home} />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  };

  // When Component has rendered, window.addEventListener adds event "load" and calls handleLoad function
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
  }

  // Fade out site-loader
  handleLoad() {
    $(".loaderSmall").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
  }
};

ReactDOM.render (
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)

// Hot Module Replacement API (injecting code)
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}

export default App;
```

..this is my menu component that renders when I am on "/archive" component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

//Menu component renders menu Link
class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to={'/#top'}>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/#about'}>About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/archive'}>Archive</Link></li>
            <li className="contactMobile"><a href="mailto:magdamargaretha@gmail.com?Subject=magdenmagden">Contact</a></li>
            <li className="contactWeb"><Link to={'/#contact'}>Contact</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

..and this is my other menu that renders when i am on root where i want scrollable hashlinks:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Scrollchor from 'react-scrollchor';

//Menu component renders menu Link
class MenuB extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><Scrollchor to="#top" animate={{offset: 20, duration: 800}}>Home</Scrollchor></li>
            <li><Scrollchor to="#about" animate={{offset: 0, duration: 800}}>About</Scrollchor></li>
            <li><Link to={'/archive'}>Archive</Link></li>
            <li className="contactMobile"><a href="mailto:magdamargaretha@gmail.com?Subject=magdenmagden">Contact</a></li>
            <li className="contactWeb"><Scrollchor to="#contact" animate={{offset: 20, duration: 800}}>Contact</Scrollchor></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuB;
```

my webpack.config.js file:

```
// DEVELOPMENT

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const entry = [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080', // bundle the client for webpack-dev-server and connect to the provided endpoint
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // bundle the client for hot reloading only- means to only hot reload for successful updates
    './app.js'
]

const output = {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist',
  filename: 'bundle.min.js'
}

const plugins = [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // enable HMR globally
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin() // prints more readable module names in the browser console on HMR updates
]

const config = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: entry,
    output: output,
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
            {
                // test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                // exclude: /node_modules/,
                // include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                // use: {
                //  loader: "eslint-loader",
                //  options: {
          //     failOnWarning: false,
          //     failOnError: false
                //  }
                // }
        },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
      {
              test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
              use: [{
                loader: 'url-loader',
          options: { limit: 10000, name: './images/[name].[ext]' }
              }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
  },
    performance: {
        maxAssetSize: 400000000,
        maxEntrypointSize: 400000000,
        hints: 'warning'
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery'
    }
}

module.exports = config
```

And my webpack.config.prod.js file:

```
//  PRODUCTION

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const entry = {
    app: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/app.js')
}

const output = {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js',
}

const plugins = [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        mangle: false,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'), // creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'index-template.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'bundle',
        filename: '[name].common.js'
    })
]

const config = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: entry,
    output: output,
    devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: "babel-loader"
            },
      {
              test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
              use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: { limit: 10000, name: './images/[name].[ext]' } // Convert images < 10k to base64 strings (all in images folder)
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                  'css-loader',
                  {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                plugins: (loader) => [ require('autoprefixer')() ]
                            }
                        },
                  'sass-loader',
                ]
              })
            }
        ]
  },
    plugins: plugins,
    externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery'
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

..I know that there are much better ways to do this than to have two menu components that renders on different pages, but I just did this solution for now .. Problem is that I don't understans how to convert this to HashHistory of BrowserHistory without loosing my logic. Any tips/input would be so goddammit appreciated, been sitting with this for weeks now <3

Comment: That message is from a server. What are you using ? Webpack dev server ?

Comment: Yes! I'll post my webpack file aswell @Panther

Comment: webpack files are posted<3 @Panther

Comment: Try adding `historyApiFallback: true` to your dev config. As quoted here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback

Comment: @Panther I already have that .. I added my package.json file above

Comment: @Panther No Panther you were totally right!! I just had to add "historyApiFallback: {
   disableDotRule: true
 }" to my dev.server.js file. Thank you a million times!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Panther solved this. To be able to refresh page in my dev environment, I had to add:

```
historyApiFallback: {
   disableDotRule: true
}
```

to my webpack dev.server file:

```
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var webpack = require('webpack');
// requiring my webpack configuration
var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
var path = require('path');

var compiler = webpack(config);
// then spinning up a new dev server with some settings
var server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    hot: true,
    filename: config.output.filename,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    proxy: {
        "/getMail": 'http://localhost:80/magdan/php/mailer.php',
        "/getProducts": 'http://localhost:80/magdan/php/products.php'
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    }
});

// its gonna listen to port 8080
server.listen(8080, 'localhost', function() {
    console.log("Starting server on http://localhost:8080");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot GET /currentPage ?

For `browserHistory` on page refresh ,`/currentPage` is requested on server side.

At the backend, your server dont defined this path (requested resource).

You need to implement it to fixed `Cannot GET` issue for page refresh.

**Assuming nodejs**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

//will serve index.html for every page refresh.
app.use('*',(req,resp)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname+'/index.html')) 
})

app.listen(someport)
```

This will  load `index.html` page for every page refresh.

Once `index.html` is loaded with required JS &  react router,

the router will trigger the route and corresponding component is getting rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your respons @RIYAJ KHAN, I got it working by adding "historyApiFallback: {
   disableDotRule: true
 }" to my dev-server.js file. So it now works in my dev environment .. We'll see if I have the same issue when I push it up live <3

Comment: it doesn't work in production :( I get error "Not Found. The requested URL /archive was not found on this server.". I'm loosing my mind with this one .. I really don't know if i have a node server, I just upload my files to my web-hotel www.one.com, bugger :(

Comment: @fransBernhard `historyApiFallback` solution working on dev right?

Comment: Yes! It works on dev, but not when i upload online☹️

Comment: Yes! It works on dev, but not when i upload online☹️ @RIYAJ KHAN